# how to store cross-domain data in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I need to know, if it´s possible in any way to store data from an chrome extension, which I can use on every website. I use the data in JS conent_scripts.

I tried cookies and iframe for localStorage workaround as desribed here: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/09/07/learning-from-xauth-cross-domain-localstorage/

But nothing really worked. Please help me.

Edit: As written below in comments, it works now with chrome.storage. Thanks!

Edit2: This doesn´t work for me:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({key: "test", value: "test Test 1234"},
                        function ()
                        {
                             console.log("had saved!");
                             chrome.storage.sync.get("test",
                                                     function (value)
                                                     {
                                                          console.log("read value: ", value);
                                                     }
                                                 );
                         }
                     );
```

The console output:

read value: Object {}

Comment: How long do you want the data to last?  Until the browser is closed?  Forever?

Comment: forever would be nice.

Comment: [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html)

Comment: chrome.storage doesn´t exist in content_scripts

Comment: Since when ??? According to **[the docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html#method-StorageArea-get)**: *Your extension's content scripts can directly access user data without the need for a background page.*

Comment: If you have managed to get it to work, please make an answer and accept it tomorrow so that other people know what worked for you.

Comment: @alpham8 The API not being listed at [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) is a bug in the documentation (reported as https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=278919). `chrome.storage` is supported in content scripts as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your new code is the following:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({test: "test Test 1234"}, function () {
    console.log("had saved!");
    chrome.storage.sync.get("test", function (value) { console.log("read value: ", value.test); } );
});
```

All objects are key-value pairs, you shouldn't add the key and value properties.

Comment: I had to use chrome.storage.local, becaus I had to save 140 kb data. But it works also, thank you!